# Why this header file include create issue?

Tags: c

I have main.c,test.c,test.h and font.h files when i try to print the buffer in font.h in main.c. Its creating compilation timer error. Anything wrong I am done? Please help.

error:

tmp/ccnygNfe.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `c'

/tmp/ccGk8E1o.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

```
/* Main.c*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include "font.h"
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    printf("c=%s",c);

    return 0;
}


/*test.c*/

#ifndef _test_
#define _test_

#include "test.h"
#include "font.h"

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+b);
}

#endif

/*test.h*/
extern void add(int a, int b);

/*font.h*/
#ifndef _font_
#define _font_

char c[10]="saji";
extern char c[10];
#endif
```

Comment: not sir. What changes that I want to make for accessing buffer in font.h?

Answer (score 2):

1. declare variable in header file, initialize variable in source file.

- font.h

```
extern char c[10];
```

- font.c

```
char c[10] = "saji\0";
```

2. there is some problem in your test.c. function signature is void, but return int.

Comment: Great answer -- but you can futher tidy it up, as you should not need the #ifndef in the header file when it only have the extern decl

Answer (score 1):

In your `font.h`, you are declaring `char c` twice:

```c
char c[10]="saji";
extern char c[10];
```

Move `extern char c[10];` into main.c / main.h. The declaration should go into the font.h, and the extern should go into the file where you are using the variable referenced with extern.